# Getting stuck in some type of mode (super key?)

Tags: keyboard, gnome-shell

Every once in a while I'll do something on my keyboard that will get my system stuck in some sort of mode where only certain keys will work, and I won't be able to type anything into text boxes. I believe I accidentally press some random buttons on my keyboard (it's a laptop), and it will get stuck.

The certain keys that work are (for example) <kbd>Q</kbd> will show a number next to each application in the program sidebar, <kbd>L</kbd> will password-lock, and <kbd>D</kbd> will show the desktop. I've got a feeling that this is related to the <kbd>super</kbd> key, or maybe the <kbd>fn</kbd> key, but I've tried almost every combination I can think of and can't exit this mode unless I restart my system.

What am I doing here / what keys am I pressing?

Answer (score 2):

Just found out that I've been pressing the <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd> all at the same time. Press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> to exit this mode.

Comment: To exit the super mode, ( Super + fn ) worked for me.

Comment: Is this specific to a certain setup or type of computer?
I tried super + fn + alt on my computer and it didn't seem to do anything

Comment: I pressed super + alt to exit the mode. My solution is in the second sentence of my answer. Hope that works for you.